# Android: How to only hear when my custom class is clicked

Tags: android, view, onclick

when I make a custom view class and add a clickListener it fires anywhere on the screen I click, even where the custom view is not. If I use the same code with a button from a layout it only fires when I click the button not anywhere on screen. Any ideas how to just only listen for when my custom class is directly clicked?

button only fire when pressed

```
   Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
   b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "button clicked");
   }
});
```

stroke object fires  when you press anywhere on screen, even outside of stroke's bounding box

```
    Stroke stroke = new Stroke(this);
    mainLayout.addView(stroke);
    stroke.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      // fires on every screen click :>(
      Log.d(Main.DEBUG_TAG, this.toString()+"shape clicked");
   }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your custom view just fills the whole screen. That's why it reacts on every click on the screen. You need to make it smaller and everything will work fine.

Comment: thanks that did it: stroke.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(5, 100));